# Module QGIS work in Pycuda processing it through the card

Tags: qgis, gpgpu

Is it possible when I speak through processing.runalg('saga:changegridvalues)
format rasters .tiff there was a process not through the processor and graphics card through, that would speed up the processing and working with rasters larger

Answer (score 3):

QGIS currently uses CPU for rendering and raster processing.

There is a [QGIS 
Plugin](https://github.com/aFuerst/PyCUDA-Raster) that uses pyCUDA, but 
it only works on Linux. I've not got a proper graphics card, so I 
can't test it :/

It implements Hillshade / Slope / Aspect, but not other algorithms.

There was a talk at the recent Scottish QGIS User Group meeting by the 
project lead. You can [see the slides here](http://www.slideshare.net/RossMcDonald1/qgis-plugin-for-parallel-processing-in-terrain-analysis) or a [YouTube video of 
the presentation](https://youtu.be/mkDMFiVLdkg).